# Ответ выводится несколько раз

Tags: javascript

Есть задание: написать программу, которая высчитывает сколько раз в числе встречается каждая его цифра. Я то написал - работает, но есть одна проблема.

Вот к примеру вводит пользователь число 123345. Цифра 3 повторяется 2 раза и alert выводит это же сообщение два раза. То есть для других цифр которые встречаются там всего один раз alert выводит одно сообщение и все нормально.
Помогите пожалуйста.

```js
function same_numbers() {
  var number = document.getElementById('number').value;
  var number_copy = number;
  var s_1 = "";
  var s_2 = "";
  var same = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < number.length; ++i) {
    same = 0;
    s_1 = number.charAt(i);
    for (y = 0; y < number_copy.length; ++y) {
      s_2 = number_copy.charAt(y);

      if (s_1 == s_2) {
        same += 1;
      }

    }
    alert(s_1 + ": " + same + ";");
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number" />
<input type="button" onclick="same_numbers()" value="Click Me" />
```

Comment: У вас алерт в цикле, поэтому и выводит несколько раз

Comment: Жаль цикл маленький, было бы больше окон.

Comment: @stackanon я когда вытаскиваю его из цикла то выводится почему то только последнее число и на этом все заканчивается

Comment: Предлагаю при помощи листика и ручки пошагово пройти весь цикл (а там всего-то 6 итераций) с разбором значений всех переменных. Более чем уверен, что решение сразу найдется)

Comment: @carapuz открываешь дебаг и жмешь на 1 клавишу, осматривая значения всех переменных. Вроде в 21 веке живем)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что внешний цикл идет по всем цифрам, и если цифра повторяется, для нее повторяется подсчет и заново происходит вывод.

Чтобы этого избежать, можно менять строку, удаляя из нее уже проверенные символы.

Например:

```js
function same_numbers() {
  var number = document.getElementById('number').value;
  var replaced;
  var same;
  var s_1;
  while (number.length) {
    s_1 = number[0];
    replaced = number.split(s_1).join('');
    same = number.length - replaced.length;
    console.log(s_1 + ": " + same + ";");
    number = replaced;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number" />
<input type="button" onclick="same_numbers()" value="Click Me" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше использовать объект для хранения результата

```js
function same_numbers() {
  var number = document.getElementById('number').value;
  var numbersCount = {};
  var val;
  for (i = 0; i < number.length; ++i) {
    val = number[i];
    numbersCount[val] ? numbersCount[val]++ : (numbersCount[val]=1)    
  }
  alert(JSON.stringify(numbersCount, null, ' '));

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number" />
<input type="button" onclick="same_numbers()" value="Click Me" />
```